# Configuring Ports.conf to Run Bugzilla on Apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, bugzilla

Using a guest VM with Ubuntu, I modified /etc/apache2/ports.conf to listen on port 8010.

After starting mysql and apache2, I went to `http://localhost:8010/bugzilla`, however I got a 404 error.

I think that my ports.conf is set up correctly since I see a 404 error, `"The requested URL /bugzilla was not found on this server"` shows up on localhost on port 8010 from the host machine.

Please check out my ports.conf and advise me.

**ports.conf**

```
NameVirtualHost *:8010
Listen 8010

#<VirtualHost *:8010>
#DocumentRoot /bugzilla
ServerName bugzilla
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

# Other directives here

#</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    # If you add NameVirtualHost *:443 here, you will also have to change
    # the VirtualHost statement in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
    # to <VirtualHost *:443>
    # Server Name Indication for SSL named virtual hosts is currently not
    # supported by MSIE on Windows XP.
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mix too many concepts: port management and DocumentRoot definition.

Here Apache does not find the directory bugzilla in your actual DdocumentRoot. It's not a probleme of port.

Often the documentRoot is in /var/www then bugzilla should be here ; regarding your actual configuration.

**edit** :

to manage the CGI you will need to add this in your httpd.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/html/bugzilla/>
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
Options +Indexes +ExecCGI
DirectoryIndex index.cgi
AllowOverride Limit
</Directory>
```

the better way is to make a dedicated [virtualhost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/fr/vhosts/examples.html) otherwise if you crash your apache config ; every service will be down.

Comment: My apache2's error.log shows "[error] [client 10.0.2.2] File does not exist: /var/www/bugzilla" I updated my /etc/apache2/httpd.conf to look for cgi files at /var/www/html/bugzilla, which is where bugzilla is located. Should I move bugzilla to /var/www/html?

Comment: of course. Otherwise how the httpd server will find it ?

Comment: Yea, good point. So http://localhost/bugzilla only shows perl code, rather than actually displaying it. Is there something I need to do so that the code executes?

Comment: no ; if you had authorized the execution of cgi in that directory that should be ok. Dont hesitate to look at the installation guide too. But again I recommand to isolate bugzilla on another vhost thus it will be more confortable to manage the config of it ;) good luck

Comment: Thank you for your help. Not sure what I did, but the Bugzilla homepage rendered after I refreshed http::/localhost/bugzilla

Comment: so "bravo" ;) and have fun with it :)